# Massive data export to CSV in Rails 4.2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, memory-management, export-to-csv, ram

I'm having RAM usage issues while export huge data to CSV file in Rails. My method responsible for csv generation:

```
def csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ';', force_quotes: true) do |csv|
    csv << headers

    cached_data.each do |cashed_object|
      # row_data is multielement(~100 elements) array of strings containing data to be presented in csv
      row_data = selected_ordered_scopes.map { |scope| cashed_object[scope.to_s] }.flatten
       csv << row_data
      end
    end
end

selected_ordered_scopes is an array: [:id, :preferences, ...]

cached_object is written in Rails.cache as following:
id => [...],
preferences => ['lorem', 'ipsum',...],
other key => ['lorem', ipsum',...]
...
```

I use gem 'get_process_mem' to analyze memory usage while executing export action in Rails app.

**When I perform two/three/four consecutive export data containing 50 000 rows (each row is cached_object data described above) I see that memory usage grows up above 2 Gb and never gets released. Do you have any idea how to deal with that?**

I would like to release memory quickly after first export or perform it somehow other way not to use so much memory.

Comment: is cached_data ever cleared or does it hold the data for the duration of the program?

Comment: @Joel_Blum cached_data is stored in Rails cache. I fetch necessary ~ 50 000 objects from rails cache. Each object has scopes like I wrote: id => ['...'], preferences => ['...', '...'] and remaining scopes. Cached_data is simply a method returning cached objects as array. I did some 'fetch in batch' to have many smaller arrays (200 cached objects) but I didn't get desired results as well.

Comment: OK. and do you ever clear Rails.cache? otherwise this will keep ballooning

Comment: @Joel_Blum Well for my purposes it is low-level caching - data to be cached is calculate-expensive, so I can't clear Rails cache.